# Django - Cannot assign, must be a instance

Tags: python, django

This issue was raised several times, though I guess I'm getting it from a different reason, or at least I can't tell how it's related.

Django: 1.10.5, Python: 3.5.2, Postgres: 9.5

So, I have such models (simplified):

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Child(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Child, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
```

I have a custom queryset:

```
class ChildQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):

    def find_recent(self):
        return self.order_by('-date_created')

Child.objects = ChildQuerySet.as_manager()
```

Then, I'm trying to test some custom queryset method for child:

```
class ChildQuerysetDatabaseIntegrationTest(TestCase): # from django.test
    default_parent = Parent()

    def setUp(self):
        super(ChildQuerysetDatabaseIntegrationTest, self).setUp()
        self.default_parent.save()

    def test_find_recent(self):
        # given
        for _ in range(1, 10):
            child = Child(self.default_parent)
            child.save()

        # when
        recent = Child.objects.find_recent()
        ordered = Child.objects.order_by('-date_created')

        # then
        self.assertEqual(list(ordered), list(recent))
```

This produces following error on the last line of test (fetching all entities):

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "UUID('...')": "Child.parent" must be a "Parent" instance.
```

Usually, when there's some mapping error, the error is thrown during entity saving, but here everything seems to persist successfully, but then fails on retrieval.

The UUID object that is tried to be assigned to parent instance, is actually child's id object, which makes me even more confused.

I tried changing object creation to Parent.objects.create(), but the result didn't change. Calling any function that retrieves a Child object, like ordered.first(), also fails, so I have no clue what's happening.

Comment: You clearly need to show the code for the manager (as in, the code for `find_recent`) for anyone to be able to help, since `find_recent` isn't vanilla Django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your custom constructor for `Child`.  When the ORM is trying to retrieve results, the overridden constructor prevents the ORM from passing in the column values to instantiate the instance properly.  In other words, the ORM is trying to pass in the values in the column-specified order, e.g.,

```
 Child(id, date_created, parent)
```

while the custom constructor expects values to be passed in the following order:

```
 Child(parent, . . .)
```

To resolve this issue, remove your custom constructor and use

```
 instance = Child(parent=parent)
```

whenever you want to initialize a child with a parent.